# Scaffold-DbContext command for EF Core for oracle database fails to generate index name in ModelContext with latest nuget packages

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, orm

I am beginner to .net core and EF. Kindly someone help with this.

Below are the steps followed.

1. created a .net 6 class library project
2. added below nuget packages

   - Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.12
   - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.12
   - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.12
   - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.120
3. Ran Scaffold-DbContext command
4. It generated ModelContext and entities. but in ModelContext, index name is null for the entity. Please see below code, specifically entity.HasIndex, it has null for index name.

   [image]

Not Facing any issues with below versions of nuget packages;

- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore - 6.21.5
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - 6.0.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.50

Comment: It is issue for Oracle. I hope they have somewhere bug tracker.